# Is this data being overwritten by another component?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, silex, serialization

I'm doing some programming in Silex with the symfony components and I think I have found a bug with the `symfony/serializer` and the `symfony/validator` components.

First let me explain what I'm traing to achieve, then let's go to the code.
My objective is to annotate a class with information like serialization directives as well as validation directives. As the reading of these annotations can cost a litle cpu, I like to cache them in memory. For this purpose, I'm using memcache wrapper in the `Doctrine/Common/Cache` package.

The problem I face is that both the `symfony/serializer` and the `symfony/validator` write Metadata to the cache using the class name as key. When they try to retrieve the metadata later, they throw an exception, because the cache has invalid metadata, either an instance of `Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata` or `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\ClassMetadataInterface`.

Following is a reproductible example (sorry if its big, I tried to make as small as possible):

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This field cannot be empty")
     */
    private $someProperty;

    /**
     * @return int
     * @Groups({"some_group"})
     */
    public function getSomeProperty() {
        return $this->someProperty;
    }
}


use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use \Memcache as MemcachePHP;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache as MemcacheWrapper;

$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

$memcache = new MemcachePHP();

if (! $memcache->connect('localhost', '11211')) {
    throw new \Exception('Unable to connect to memcache server');
}

$cacheDriver = new MemcacheWrapper();
$cacheDriver->setMemcache($memcache);

$app = new \Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SerializerServiceProvider());

$app['serializer.normalizers'] = function () use ($app, $cacheDriver) {
    $classMetadataFactory = new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory(
        new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()), $cacheDriver);

    return [new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer($classMetadataFactory) ];
};

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider(), [
    'validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory' =>
        new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Factory\LazyLoadingMetadataFactory(
            new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()),
            new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache($cacheDriver)
        )
]);

$app->get('/', function(\Silex\Application $app) {
    $foo = new Foo();

    $app['validator']->validate($foo);
    $json = $app['serializer']->serialize($foo, 'json');

    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($json, \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_OK, [], true);
});

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, $code) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.' . $e->getMessage());
});

$app->run();
```

After running this example you get fatal errors.
Can anyone confirm that I'm not making a hard mistake here?

Currently my workaround for this is rewrite the `DoctrineCache` class making use of a namespace for the cache keys. Its working, but I think its ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is two separate `CacheDrivers`. See https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php for how namespaces are used there.

You could:

```
$validatorCacheDriver = new MemcacheWrapper();
$validatorCacheDriver->setMemcache($memcache);
$validatorCacheDriver->setNamespace('symfony_validator');

$serializerCacheDriver = new MemcacheWrapper();
$serializerCacheDriver->setMemcache($memcache);
$serializerCacheDriver->setNamespace('symfony_serializer');

// note that the two drivers are using the same memcache instance, 
// so only one connection will be used.

$app['serializer.normalizers'] = function () use ($app, $serializerCacheDriver) {
    $classMetadataFactory = new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory(
        new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()), $serializerCacheDriver);

    return [new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer($classMetadataFactory) ];
};

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider(), [
    'validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory' =>
        new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Factory\LazyLoadingMetadataFactory(
            new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()),
            new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache($validatorCacheDriver)
        )
]);
```

I've trimmed the code to only show the parts that play some part in the solution. I hope this helps!